# gql: delete row by id only if relations empty

Tags: graphql, apollo, hasura, gql

I want delete row by id only if it not related with other tables.

My SQL (postgres) is:

```
DELETE FROM material m
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT FROM material m
    LEFT JOIN project_material pm on m.id = pm.material
    LEFT JOIN project_materialset_material pmm on m.id = pmm.material
    LEFT JOIN materialset_material mm on m.id = mm.material
    WHERE (pmm.id IS NOT NULL OR
        pm.id IS NOT NULL OR
        mm.id IS NOT NULL ) AND m.id=13
)
AND m.id=13
    
RETURNING m.id;
```

What GQL mutation should I use for this query?

**UPDATE**
GQL (result is `[]`, but not related `material` exists):

```
query M {
  material(where: {
    project_materials: {
      id: {
          _is_null: true
      }
    }
    project_materialset_materials: {
      id: {
          _is_null: true
      }
    }
    materialset_materials: {
      id: {
          _is_null: true
      }
    }
  }
  )
    {
    id
    project_materials {
      id
    }
    project_materialset_materials {
      id
    }
    materialset_materials {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

When I replaced `id` to `material` in `where`, result was empty too.

Comment: Hi friend, in the Hasura schema you should be able to say "where nested object ID = null" https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/databases/postgres/mutations/delete/#delete-objects-based-on-nested-objects-fields

Comment: Maybe you can do it by making first query to check the related tables and then based on that result delete. Seems not possible in single mutation.

Comment: Also I can make an action, query to backend to execute sql there or smth else. No. Question is "delete with this case or return `affecting_row==0`". I try to use `_is_null` with `_or` / `_and` modificators but did not succeed.

Comment: @tannerman Can you please update the question to show the GQL mutation that you've tried so far that includes the _is_null, _or, _and

Comment: @Jesse Carter, I update question. Anyway how common where block read entities - as `_or` or `_and`, result would be not empty.

Comment: The way you've written your query all of the statements will be compared using `AND`. So you will only find records where project_materials is null AND project_materialset_materials is null AND materialset_materials is null.

It sounds like what you actually want is an OR comparison? In which case they need to be wrapped inside of `_or`